# F# wrapper to generate SHA256 signature for a file

Tags: file, cryptography, f#, wrapper, hashcode

I've created the following module to allow me to generate a SHA256 signature for a file. (In real life this is used to verify an image file hasn't been amended).  The cut down code looks like this:

```
open System.IO
open System.Text
open System.Security.Cryptography;


// Get the SHA256 hash of a file
let SHA256 (file:FileInfo) =
    let FileSHA256Wrap (hashFile : FileStream) (sha256Hash : SHA256)  : byte[] = 
        sha256Hash.ComputeHash(hashFile)
    let FileWrap (hashFile : FileStream) : byte[] =
        using (SHA256Managed.Create()) (FileSHA256Wrap hashFile)
    using (file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) FileWrap

// Convert the byte[] version of the hash to a printable encoded HEX string
let HexEncoded (hash:byte[]) :string =
    let sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2)
    hash |> Array.map (fun c -> sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}",c)) |> ignore
    sb.ToString()

// Get the file hash and convert it to a HEX string
let HexEncodedSHA256 (file:FileInfo) =
    file |> SHA256 |> HexEncoded


let fi = new FileInfo("somefile.tif")
HexEncodedSHA256 fi
```

I've two questions here, with the double `using` statements I find the wrap functions help me work out what is going on - but is there a neater and more succinct way to write this without making it hard to work out what is happening?

The implementation of HexEncoded uses a string builder, is there a more *functional* way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use` binding is usually better than the `using` function. The object is disposed when leaving the scope of the `use` binding (when leaving the `SHA256` function).

```
let SHA256 (file:FileInfo) =
    use hashFile = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    use sha256Hash = SHA256Managed.Create()
    sha256Hash.ComputeHash(hashFile)
```

You can avoid the use of a string builder by using `String.concat`. You can also use the F# `sprintf` function, which has slightly different format specifier syntax.

```
let HexEncoded (hash:byte[]) :string =
    hash
    |> Array.map (sprintf "%02X")
    |> String.concat ""
```

This might be slightly slower than your string builder because it requires an intermediate array. (Note that your implementation could remove the intermediate array by using `Array.iter` instead of `Array.map` and moving the `ignore` to inside the lambda.)

Comment: The use binding is clearer, I was sort of trying to re-invent it with my wrap functions.

Answer (score 3):

I can only agree with TheQuickBrownFox.

You can make even more dedicated functions and then compose them like:

```
let computeHash (dataStream: Stream) (hasher: HashAlgorithm) = hasher.ComputeHash(dataStream)
let openFile (fileInfo: FileInfo) = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)

let getHash algorithmFactory fileInfo = 
    use hasher = algorithmFactory()
    use stream = openFile fileInfo
    computeHash stream hasher

let hexEncode hash = String.Join ("", hash |> Array.map (sprintf "%02X"))

let fromAlgorithm algorithmFactory fileInfo = fileInfo |> getHash algorithmFactory |> hexEncode

let fromSHA256 = fromAlgorithm SHA256Managed.Create
let fromSHA512 = fromAlgorithm SHA512Managed.Create
let fromMD5 = fromAlgorithm MD5.Create
```

As shown, in this way it's easy to change the hash algorithm.

```
let test () =
    let fi = new FileInfo(fileName)
    printfn "%A" (fromSHA256 fi)
    printfn "%A" (fromSHA512 fi)
    printfn "%A" (fromMD5 fi)
```

Comment: Note that F#'s `String.concat` calls .NET's `String.Join`, so you can use `String.concat` and maintain the pipeline style like in my answer, without changing behaviour or performance 

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: OK, thanks. I just thought I had to do something different than you :-)